# Enviar formulario al cargar pagina PHP / JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php

sucede que tengo un formulario en el cual solo filtra fechas y años, la cuestión es que el formulario funciona bien al entrar a la pagina y filtrar los datos de forma manual, la situación es que necesito que al entrar a la pagina se carguen los datos automáticamente, ya tengo los "value" con los filtros que necesito que se carguen, tengo un script que envía el formulario al cargar la pagina, solo que entra como en un loop y nunca termina.
Buscando en diferentes foros necesito colocarle un break a mi JS, la situación es que no encuentro la linea en donde ponerla para que al cargar la pagina simule un click y se detenga. Adjunto mi código.

```
<html lang="es">
<div class="right_col" role="main"><!-- page content -->
        <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                         <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Reporte Consultas</h2>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- form search -->
                        <body onLoad="enviar()">
                        <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
            <label>Fecha Desde:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"  name="date1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/>
            <label>Hasta</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="End" name="date2" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/>
            <label>Año a Comparar</label>
            <?php $cont = date('Y');?> 
            <select class="form-control" name="date3" required >
            <option selected="" value="2021">-- Selecciona --</option>
            <?php while ($cont >= 2018) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo($cont); ?>"><?php echo($cont); ?></option>
            <?php $cont = ($cont-1); } ?>
            </select>  
      <button  class="cargar" onclick='myFunction()' name="search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> <a href="consultasp" type="button"  class="btn btn-warning"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"><span></a>
        
    </form>
    
        </div>
                        <!-- end form search -->
```

Aquí el SCRIPT.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".cargar").click();
});
function myFunction(){

}

        </script>
```

Funciona el código, el problema es que nunca termina de cargar y entra en un loop, solo que pretendo es que tenga un solo click al cargar la pagina.

Comment: No parece haber un loop... que te aparece en la consola de javascript? podría ser mas bien un error que no permite que el script continue... que un loop infinito...

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusión:**
El error se debe a que estás llamando la función .click justo cuando la página se termina de cargar, lo que crea un bucle infinito.

**Solución:**
Eliminar el ready y colocar el $(".cargar").click(); dentro de tu función, esto hará que solo al hacer un click se ejecutará tu función sin caer en un bucle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    console.log("Ejemplo");
    //$(".cargar").click();
  }
</script>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Es verdad, funciona pero solo al hacer un click de forma manual, lo que pretendo es que al cargar la pagina, se carguen los datos de ese botón al hacer click, sigo igual, al final del camino se tiene que dar click manual para que se carguen los datos.